# Independence test for continuous random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, chi-squared-test, independence

For discrete random variables, chi square test of independence is a general test. By general I mean it is not possible for chi square statistic to be 0 when the variables are not independent. For the case of continuous random variables common measures of dependence are usually correlation based measures. But these tests do not have the property that I have explained, that is, even if, for example, the Pearson correlation between two variables is 0, they can still be strongly associated. For example, if the values of the two variables, when plotted, have a circular shape then the correlation value will be 0 but they are strongly associated with each other. My question is: is there some general test of independence (in the sense I defined above) for continuous random variables? My second question is: if there is such a test, why is it not popular as much as Pearson correlation? This second question is somewhat subjective but maybe you can answer.

Comment: Check [BDS test](http://www.eviews.com/help/helpintro.html#page/content/advtimeser-BDS_Independence_Test.html).